# getting undefined while displaying array on table

Tags: javascript

i have a function to create a schedule i have a class schedule then an array which stores the objects created but when i try displaying the objects in a table i get undefined

```
const mySchedules=[];
class Schedule {
    constructor(name, subject, time, day) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.time = time;
        this.day = day;

    }
}



function create() {

    let
        name = document.getElementById("name").value,
        subject = document.getElementById("subject").value,
        time = document.getElementById("time").value,
        day = document.getElementById("day").value,
        table = document.getElementById("table")


    mySchedules.push(new Schedule(name, subject, time, day))


//create object
    let obj = new Schedule();

// Create Row
    let row = `<tr>
               <td>${obj.name}</td>
               <td>${obj.subject}</td>
               <td>${obj.time}</td>
               <td>${obj.day}</td>
             </tr>`;

    table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", row);

}
```

Comment: `let obj = new Schedule();` <= no arguments are given to the constructor.  Why do you even need that variable.  `obj` should be set to the schedule you created and appended to the array.  Not a new empty one

Comment: You don't have to use this `let obj = new Schedule();` because it is empty, instead you can loop through `mySchedules` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object `obj` that you're trying to reference is empty, because you called your constructor with no agruments, as Taplar said above:

`let obj = new Schedule()`

You need to call it with your arguments:

`let obj = new Schedule(name, subject, time, day)`

In which case your `mySchedules` array is pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

By doing this `let obj = new Schedule();` you are initializing your object to empty schedule which makes`name` property of `obj` and other properties undefined.

Changing your code like this would help.

```
const mySchedules=[];
class Schedule {
    constructor(name, subject, time, day) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.time = time;
        this.day = day;

    }
}



function create() {

    let
        name = document.getElementById("name").value,
        subject = document.getElementById("subject").value,
        time = document.getElementById("time").value,
        day = document.getElementById("day").value,
        table = document.getElementById("table")

    // store the schedule in a variable
    let schedule = new Schedule(name, subject, time, day);

    mySchedules.push(schedule)


//create object
   let obj = schedule;

// Create Row
    let row = `<tr>
               <td>${obj.name}</td>
               <td>${obj.subject}</td>
               <td>${obj.time}</td>
               <td>${obj.day}</td>
             </tr>`;

    table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", row);

}
```